# Writing scope for a has_many belongs_to Association - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, so your help and advise would be much appreciated.

> aim:

- what i aim to do is to display only application forms belonging to adverts that have not expired.
- currently i have a user who has applied to all the job adverts
- at present - i have 3 adverts created - 2 are active and 1 has expired
- i can count all the users application forms by `@user.forms.count` - this will display all the forms for all the adverts
- could one advise me how i display only the user's forms of adverts that have not been expired

> models

```
user.rb
has_many forms

form.rb
belongs_to user
belongs_to advert

advert.rb
has_may forms

scope :active_adverts, -> {where(['deadline >= ?', Date.current])}
```

> users_controller.rb

```
  def dashboard
    if current_user
      @user = User.find(current_user)
      @user_applications = @user.forms
      @form = @user.forms.find(params[:id])
    else  
      redirect_to error_path
    end
  end
```

i tried this in the view "views/users/dashboard.html.erb" `<%= @user.forms.where(advert: @form.advert.active_advert).count %>` but i've come to realise that will not work. you advise will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define `scope` like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forms
  has_many :adverts, through: :forms # <-- The change here
end

class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forms
  scope :active, -> { where('deadline > ?', Time.now) } # <-- The change here
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :advert
end
```

So your `count function` will be:

```
@users.adverts.active.count
```